# using sapply on a vector of dates

Tags: r

I have a function that adds a random integer to a date:

```
rand_to_date = function(date){
newdate = as.Date(date) + sample(1:30, 1)
return(as.Date(newdate))
}
```

which works fine. However, if I attempt to use sapply to apply this function to a vector of dates, e.g.

```
test_dates = c('2001-01-01', '2002-02-02', '2003-03-03', '2004-04-04')
```

sapply will not return a vector of output in date format:

```
 sapply(test_dates,rand_to_date)
 2001-01-01 2002-02-02 2003-03-03 2004-04-04 
 11329      11748      12115      12513
```

In contrast, lapply will return a list of dates. However, applying unlist to this output once again gives me a vector of numbers rather than dates. Nor does

```
sapply(sapply(test,rand_to_date), as.Date)
```

work. What's the simplest way for me to give a vector of these randomized dates as output?

Comment: `as.Date(test_dates) + sample(1:30, length(test_dates), replace = TRUE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** Owing to the existence of the `c.Date` method, use `lapply` and then `c`.  We have also simplified `rand_to_date` and added `set.seed` to make it reproducible:

```
rand_to_date <- function(date) as.Date(date) + sample(30, 1)

set.seed(123)
test_dates <- c('2001-01-01', '2002-02-02', '2003-03-03', '2004-04-04')

do.call("c", lapply(test_dates, rand_to_date))
## [1] "2001-01-10" "2002-02-26" "2003-03-16" "2004-05-01"
```

**2)** Alternately, we could make rand_to_date vectorized right off like this:

```
rand_to_date <- function(date) as.Date(date) + sample(30, length(date), TRUE)

set.seed(123)
test_dates <- c('2001-01-01', '2002-02-02', '2003-03-03', '2004-04-04')
rand_to_date(test_dates)
## [1] "2001-01-10" "2002-02-26" "2003-03-16" "2004-05-01"
```

Comment: As a fun fact, I guess the `purrr` equivalent to this is `reduce(map(test_dates, rand_to_date), c)`, for what its worth.

Comment: or `invoke("c", map(test_dates, rand_to_date))`

Comment: Thanks, using do.call does seem like the most streamlined solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `sapply` discards attributes, including the S3 class — this is unrelated to your function; `sapply(test_dates, as.Date)` fails in the same way.

You need to add them again:

```
structure(sapply(test_dates,rand_to_date), 'Date')
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that sapply removes class attributes - I thought at first that it was something specific to dates as a variable class.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert the number back to a date.

```
as.Date(sapply(test_dates, rand_to_date), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.character()` within `sapply` :

```
sapply(test_dates,function(v) as.character(rand_to_date(v)),USE.NAMES = F)
```

where `as.character(rand_to_date(v))` gives date as `character`, instead of `POSIXct` type.